# Does [NSDate distantPast] always give same value?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

Does `[NSDate distantPast]` always give same value. My scenario is that I want to assign some past value to a property and then check it with equality again with `[NSDate distantPast]`. Eg.

At some point of code I did this:
`NSDate *myVar = [NSDate distantPast];`

Then at some later point I want to check whether this is still valid.

```
if(myVar == [NSDate distantPast]) {
    NSLog(@"Still Equal.");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Not equal now.");
}
```

If not, then what should be the correct way to store some past value as a start value.

Comment: What does this "distant past" mean in your code?

Comment: Basically, I wanted to start with some default value and was thinking of giving epoch(1970-01-01 00:00:00) value but then found `distantPast`. So distant past is some past value which I can safely use as default start value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't test `NSDate` with `==` operator. It will return `YES` only if it is the same instance.
You should use the `isEqualToDate:` method for that.

And for your Q, you shouldn't count on it that it will be the same date, although I guess it will be the same. I think your first think is better (using default distance date), even though other solutions should be even more readable (leave it as nil, save a flag and etc.)...

Good luck.